# Get value with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have

```
`<button class="button button--chromeless" data-action="select-anchor" data-action-value="fba4">Top highlight</button>`
```

I need get result "fba4" from data-action-value.

I tried:

```
IWebElement ell = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[data-action-value]"));
```

I think that I need be based on Top highlight to get value fba4 but I don't know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.GetAttribute("data-action-value")`

```
 string element  = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[data-action-value]")).GetAttribute("data-action-value");
```

You can also use below Xpath

```
//button[@class='button button--chromeless']/@data-action-value
```

You can use

```
string element  = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("button button--chromeless")).GetAttribute("data-action-value");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: 'ell' should be of return type 'string' instead of 'IWebElement'

Comment: That's work but I get result from first button, how I can defined for example second, can I add somewhere [1]

Comment: means you have many button with same class name? and you want to select any particular one

Comment: Yes, how I can defined it?

Comment: if class name "button button--chromeless " is unique then you can use string element  = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("button button--chromeless")).GetAttribute("data-action-value");

Comment: if not then you can use xpath with array like

Comment: //button[@class='button button--chromeless'][2]/@data-action-value

Comment: string element  = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='button button--chromeless'][2]/@data-action-value")).GetAttribute("data-action-value");

Comment: here you can observe that I have use [2] .. it means 2nd element .. just replace the array value according to your need

Comment: I tried with numbers from 0 - 2 but don't works I always get Invalid selector , are you sure that's code is ok?

Comment: if your other tags is a button, having classname as "button button--chromeless'" and having attribute data-action-value then it should work.. post some of your other require HTML code

Answer (score 1):

To get 'fba4' from the above HTML, try-

```
string ell = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[class='button button--chromeless']")).GetAttribute("data-action-value");
```

Comment: I have few buttons and I get result from first, how I can defined which one button I want example [2].

Comment: Sorry, got busy with something important. Glad you got the answer.