# How can get a href in Selenium Test using c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to select My jobs tag and then on that but there's no Id or Name for given tag just a href but when i am trying to find my cssSelector or by cssClass then it's shows erorr.So any one who can help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PWsZ.jpg)

Comment: Maybe someone could help you if you show your problematic code and error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value with Selenium C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937489/get-value-with-selenium-c-sharp)

Comment: From the question it seems you're looking for a selector to reliably find the element. These cases typically call for an xpath or CSS selector. I recommend a little study, perhaps a tutorial on xpath selectors.

Comment: @Ubaid Ur Rahman try this xpath //a[text(),'My Jobs']

Answer (score 0):

For clicking on **My Jobs** , you can use this code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("My Jobs"));  
element.Click();
```

For clicking on **New Jobs** , you can use this code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("New Jobs"));
element.Click();
```

For clicking on **My Units** , you can use this code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("My Units"));
element.Click();
```

For clicking on **Timesheets** , you can use this code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Timesheets"));
element.Click();
```

Hope this will work for you!
Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.